# How to explain the results of the following integrals?

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

Why does the following program lead to different results of `a21` and `a211`?

```
moveconst[x_] := (x /. Integrate[factor_ expr_, {var_, min_, max_}] /; 
      FreeQ[factor, var] :> factor Integrate[expr, {var, min, max}]);

inta1 = 2 (2 Cos[q3[t]] fec1[x1] q5[t] - fe1[x1] Sin[q3[t]] );
a1 = Integrate[inta1, {x1, 0, L1}] q6[t];

inta2 = (4 Cos[q3[t]] fec1[x1] q5[t] q6[t] -2 fe1[x1] Sin[q3[t]] q6[t]);
a2 = Integrate[inta2, {x1, 0, L1}];

a21 = a1 - a2;
Simplify[a21, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, moveconst}]


inta11 = 4 Cos[q3[t]] fec1[x1] q5[t] - 2 fe1[x1] Sin[q3[t]] ;
a11 = Integrate[inta11, {x1, 0, L1}] q6[t];

inta21 = (4 Cos[q3[t]] fec1[x1] q5[t] q6[t] - 2 fe1[x1] Sin[q3[t]] q6[t]);
a21 = Integrate[inta21, {x1, 0, L1}];

a211 = a11 - a21;
Simplify[a211, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, moveconst}]
```

Comment: Constants get pulled out of indefinite integrals but do  not get pulled out of definite integrals. 

One major reason for this is that definite integrals may not exist while indefinite ones do.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `Simplify` doesn't pull out numerical factors in certain integrals. A simple example being:

```
Simplify[Integrate[4 - 2 f[x], x] - 2 Integrate[2 - f[x], x]]
```

> $\int (4-2 f[x]) \, dx-2 \int (2-f[x]) \, dx$

A workaround for your code is to add explicit factoring in your transformation function:

```
moveconst[x_] := (Map[Factor, x, -1] /. 
    Integrate[factor_ expr_, {var_, min_, max_}] /; 
      FreeQ[factor, var] :> factor Integrate[expr, {var, min, max}]);
```